# JSON arrays thought

Tags: arrays, json

So I am trying to think about how I would write out the JSON code for music. I need to make a text file of the following for class and I have no idea where to start.

2 albums, 4 song each at least. 
Albums should include: name of album, name of artist, year released.
Song information should include: Song Title, Playtime

Songs should be represented as an ARRAY of OBJECTS.

ok so is something like this valid?

```
{
 "title" : "The Avairy”,
 "artist" : "Galantis”,
 "year_released" : 2017,
 "song_title" : "Hey Alligator”,
 "song_time" : 197,
 “song_title” : “True Feeling”,
 “song_time”: 214,
 “song_title” : “Written in the scars”
 “song_time” : 194,
 “song_title” : “No Money”
 “song_time” : 185;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to understand arrays, objects and JSON to fully grasp your project. Start researching each down the line.

Comment: The characters representing an array are ```[ ]```. You should do as Tim Hallman said and look into JSON representations of data first.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Object is just a dictionary mapping between keys and values.  For instance, a song could be:

```
{
    "title" : "Gangnam Style",
    "artist" : "Psy",
    "year_released" : 2012
}
```

Note that 2012 is not in quotes- this is because it is a Number, rather than a String type.  You can read more about how to format objects [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp).

To make this into an array, you just comma separate your list of objects within brackets, like so:

```
[{...},{...},{...},{...}]
```

You can also read more about arrays [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp).

Comment: ok so is something like this valid?

{
    "title" : "The Avairy"
    "artist" : "Galantis"
    "year_released" : 2017
    "song_title" : "Hey Alligator"
    "song_time" : 3.29
}

Comment: @JoelBluestein 1) you need commas between each of the terms (see example) 2) decimal numbers are not allowed.  Either it needs to be an integer, or a floating point number.  My recommendation would be to store it in seconds rather than minutes.

Comment: { "title" : "The Avairy”,
 "artist" : "Galantis”,
 "year_released" : 2017,
 "song_title" : "Hey Alligator”,
 "song_time" : 197,
 “song_title” : “True Feeling”,
 “song_time”: 214,
 “song_title” : “Written in the scars”
 “song_time” : 194,
 “song_title” : “No Money”
 “song_time” : 185;
}


this is what I came out with. Should the album itself be in an object?